# New capacitor in old Husqvarna 215 sewing machine

Tags: capacitor

I just put in a new capacitor in my old Husqvarna 215 sewing machine. The old one burned while I was sewing costumes for my kids.

I have soldered the capacitor, and the soldering seems OK, but the machine turns when I plug it in. That means I cannot stop the machine when power is on. Can you help me? The print seems very simple to me.

Comment: Welcome! Please show with a picture. Do you have access to a multimeter?

Comment: Could you show some photos of the old cap (if you have it), and the new cap as connected to the wiring around it? there are some instructions for image uploads [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/186121) in case you run into any trouble.

Comment: It's not a cap issue. You connected something wrong.

Comment: I will try to upload a picture of the print.